# parse maven output in real time using sed

Tags: parsing, sed, grep, flush

I am trying to parse my mvn verify output to only show lines with INFO tags. Please note that maven outputs line to stdout *in real time* and not by batch. I do not think that it is a problem with maven.

At first I tried to do it with grep:

```
$ mvn verify | grep INFO
```

but didn't seem to output lines in real time, as I understand grep buffers its lines before outputting, so I have to wait a few seconds between each flush and then I have tens of lines being printed at the same time, not very convenient. Then I thought I would try with sed.

According to this [link](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-15b), the following command:

```
sed -n '/PATTERN/p' file
// is equivalent to 
grep PATTERN file
```

and according to this [link](http://swtch.com/plan9port/man/man1/sed.html), the -l option should force sed to flush its output buffer after every newline. So now I am using this command:

```
 $ mvn verify | sed -ln -e '/INFO/p'
```

but I'm still getting the same result as before, I get a ton of output flushed every 30s or so and I don't know what I've done wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: It is very likely that `mvn` is buffering its output.   In general, if a program is writing to a pipe, its output will be buffered.

Comment: try `unbuffer mvn ...` if your system has `unbuffer` available. Good luck.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I am afraid you are right, none of the other solutions worked so far. I would have thought otherwise as the output keeps printing lines all the time so it looks like it is flushing to stdout after every new line. Is there a way to check that for sure?

Comment: The default behavior is exactly what you describe.  When writing to a tty, output is line buffered.  When writing to a pipe or regular file (or really anything that is not a tty) the output is line buffered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem, I was using a script to colorise maven output (see [here](https://gist.github.com/1027800)) and in fact it was that script that was buffering the output down the pipe. I forgot about it as I was using it as an alias, I guess this is a good lesson, I won't alias as easily in the future. Anyway here is the fix, I changed `-e` to `-le` in the last line of the sed call:

```
  mvn $@ | sed -e "s/\(\[INFO\]\ \-.*\)/${TEXT_BLUE}${BOLD}\1/g" \
               -e "s/\(\[INFO\]\ \[.*\)/${RESET_FORMATTING}${BOLD}\1${RESET_FORMATTING}/g" \
               -e "s/\(\[INFO\]\ BUILD SUCCESSFUL\)/${BOLD}${TEXT_GREEN}\1${RESET_FORMATTING}/g" \
               -e "s/\(\[WARNING\].*\)/${BOLD}${TEXT_YELLOW}\1${RESET_FORMATTING}/g" \
               -e "s/\(\[ERROR\].*\)/${BOLD}${TEXT_RED}\1${RESET_FORMATTING}/g" \
               -le "s/Tests run: \([^,]*\), Failures: \([^,]*\), Errors: \([^,]*\), Skipped: \([^,]*\)/${BOLD}${TEXT_GREEN}Tests run: \1${RESET_FORMATTING}, Failures: ${BOLD}${TEXT_RED}\2${RESET_FORMATTING}, Errors: ${BOLD}${TEXT_RED}\3${RESET_FORMATTING}, Skipped: ${BOLD}${TEXT_YELLOW}\4${RESET_FORMATTING}/g"
```

In effect this is telling sed to flush its output at every new line, which is what I wanted. I am sorry I didn't find another workaround that is more generic. I tried playing around with [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) (see [man](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/empty/) page) and [script](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?script) but none of these solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, if your grep supports it:

```
mvn verify | grep --line-buffered INFO
```

If you're doing this in a terminal and still seeing buffered results, it would probably be something earlier than grep doing the buffering, but I'm not familiar with `mvn`. (And, yes, the `-l` option to `sed` should have done the same thing, so the problem may be upstream.)

Comment: That didn't work either. Do you think it could be caused by the pipe?

Comment: The pipe shouldn't matter (assuming you're on a Unix-based OS). I wonder if `mvn` buffers its output when it's not writing to a terminal.

Comment: I think you are right here. I am looking into [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) (see [man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/empty.1.html) page) to make maven believe it is writing to a tty when instead writing to a pipe. Will keep updated later.

Answer (score 1):

try this line:

```
mvn verify | while read line; do echo $line|grep INFO; done
```